# DNS. Non-authoritative answer. canonical name

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a DNS understanding problem. (Using Windows AD integrated DNS, Windows 2012)

I'm trying to find out why I get the reply I get.

When going to "www.company.cn" I get an internal IP. But I do not have any records in my DNS with "www.company.cn"

A few NSLOOKUP results:

**The simple one:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup
Default Server:  DC.company.net
Address:  192.168.0.5

> www.company.cn
Server:  DC.company.net
Address:  192.168.0.5

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.company.dk
Address:  192.168.0.15
Aliases:  www.company.cn
> exit
```

As I understand, the "Non-authoritative answer" tells me its not from my local DNS I get the data (Also I do not have a company.cn zone in my DNS)

**More NSLOOKUP:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup -type=soa www.company.cn
Server:  DC.company.net
Address:  192.168.0.5

Non-authoritative answer:
www.company.cn     canonical name = www.company.dk
```

So it tells me it's from a CNAME record? (And somehow related to "www.company.**dk**")

I do have a "www.company.dk" DNS entry in my DNS:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup
Default Server:  DC.company.net
Address:  192.168.0.5

> www.company.dk
Server:  DC.company.net
Address:  192.168.0.5

Name:    www.company.dk
Address:  192.168.0.15
```

If I try the nslookup SOA command on www.google.com, I get another, more usefull answer:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup -type=soa www.google.com
Server:  DC.company.net
Address:  192.168.0.5

google.com
    primary name server = ns1.google.com
    responsible mail addr = dns-admin.google.com
    serial  = 180758758
    refresh = 900 (15 mins)
    retry   = 900 (15 mins)
    expire  = 1800 (30 mins)
    default TTL = 60 (1 min)
ns1.google.com  internet address = 216.239.32.10
```

So here it tells me the name server where it got the reply from. (which understandably is not a local server, and not within my control)

In general I just want to know where I can control the DNS record of "www.company.cn"

How can I get more useful information as to where to control www.company.cn?

Answer (score 0):

In the last query you asked your local DNS server about google,unless your company is google.com the  SOA lookup for google tells you nothing about your local DNS zones, only that you can resolve public/internet zones.
Did you mean to ask googleDNS about your domain, to see your records are in public DNS; if so you wanted

```
nslookup -type=soa company.cn. 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your Domain DNS from where you have purchased it. It is called Domain registrar. They should have provided you a controlpanel from where you can change the DNS records. If you want to manage the DNS of your domain other than your domain registrar, you will need to set nameservers of that third-party DNS service. By default, there will be domain registrars' nameservers. Any DNS changes may take some time in propagation.

So you have two options.

(1) Use Domain registrar to control your DNS records

(2) Use third-party DNS to control your DNS records (Here you need to set nameserver at Domain registrar)